# Select cells by condition and print them in different range

Tags: excel, vba

I want code to:
For keywords that their "Rank B" is lower than "Rank A", take only the first 3 that have the highest score and put them, along with their score, under the "selected" table on the right.

[image]

I've been trying to collect them to an array.

Update:
I used Dy.Lee solution, it works, unless I have a big table (300 Rows, 12 Columns), then it fails on the following line:

[image]

[image]

I found the problem, I had 2 identical column in the end of the table. Any way to catch this exception?

Comment: Use a scripting dictionary with keys and items.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim rngDB As Range

    vDB = Range("a1").CurrentRegion

    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        If vDB(i, 3) > vDB(i, 4) Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 2, 1 To n)
            vR(1, n) = vDB(i, 1)
            vR(2, n) = vDB(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    Range("g1").CurrentRegion.Offset(2).Clear
    If n = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No data matches the condition!!"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf n = 1 Then
        Range("g3").Resize(n, 2) = vR
    Else
        Range("g3").Resize(n, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    End If
    Set rngDB = Range("g2").Resize(n + 1, 2)
    rngDB.Sort key1:=Range("h2"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    rngDB.Offset(4).Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, this works amazing! Thank you! if you don't mind, can you please explain how you did it?

Comment: I see I can extend the number of keywords to be taken out if I change the offset value in the last row, still not sure why

Comment: @sale108, if 5 rngDB.Offset(4).Clear  to  rngDB.Offset(6).Clear  if 4  to rngDB.Offset(5).Clear

Comment: thank you again! I have just one more problem, it seems that I exceed some sort of limit, I am not sure what is the origin of the error... maybe you can help me with that too? it's updated above in the thread.

Comment: @sale108, can you show the sheet of  table (300 Rows, 12 Columns).

Comment: Hey man, actually, I found out that the size is not the problem. The problem is the exceptions. When there are less than 3 words that meet the terms (Rank B is lower than Rank A). and then it fails on line "Range("g3").Resize(n, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)". I want excel to print the result if there's only one word that meet the requirements.

Comment: If n=1 then Range("g3").Resize(n, 2) = vR elseif n>1 then Range("g3").Resize(n, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)

Comment: Elseif n= 0 then exit sub  end if

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to a formula solution instead of VBA, you could go with - entered as individual array formulas in each cell (ctrl+shift+enter):

```
G3-G5: {=INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(1,INDEX(($B$2:$B$8=LARGE($B$2:$B$8*--($C$2:$C$8>$D$2:$D$8),ROWS(G$2:G2)))*(COUNTIF(G$2:G2,$A$2:$A$8)=0),),0))}
```

And in column H, entered as individual array formulas (ctrl+shift+enter):

```
H3-5: {=LARGE($B$2:$B$8*--($C$2:$C$8>$D$2:$D$8),row()-2)}
```

Attached is a screenshot to see it in use. Generally, I'd recommend against using VBA for something you could solve with formulas, but that's just me.
[Screenshot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZBy2.png)

Comment: Thanks man, it could have work just fine, only problem is when I have two different words with the same score, and then it takes the higher one in the column twice. Appreciate it!

Comment: You were right. I have updated the formula to account for repeated scores, it should work as expected now.

Comment: I Would consider replacing it. Hope it's not too much trouble, do you mind explaining how you built it? how it works? I would love to use it, but since I know programming but not EXCEL formulas, in case I need to change stuff, it's much easier for me to try to understand what needs to be changed in VBA than formulas. But if you'll help me understand a little bit how it works? Thanks!!

Comment: Hey man! this also works great, just few questions, if I want it to give back 5 keywords? what should I change? Also, if I want to change the term, for example when Rank A equals = "-" and Rank B is not equal to  "-"??